# How to dockerize reverse proxy nginx routing to 1 react and 1 express app? I am getting Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, mern

I have created docker files for 1 react app, 1 express api backend server and 1 nginx server which I want as reverse proxy for react and express apps. I am getting **502 Bad Gateway** and I am unable to figure out why nginx is not able to forward the requests.

---

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: mern-reverse-proxy
    build: ./reverse-proxy
    container_name: mern-app-reverse-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  client:
    image: mern-react
    build: ./client
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    container_name: mern-app-client
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    depends_on:
      - reverse-proxy
  server:
    image: mern-express
    build: ./server
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    container_name: mern-app-server
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    depends_on:
      - reverse-proxy
```

---

react-dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

---

express-dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

---

nginx-dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

---

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

  sendfile on;

  server {
    listen 80;

    location /api {
      proxy_pass         http://server;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://client;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Is it because of the ports or proxy_pass in nginx.conf? I have exposed port 80 in all 3 containers because of reverse proxy but haven't mapped the ports of client and server services as they lie in the same network? I would be very grateful if somebody can help. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Have you changed anything in the Express servers to listen on a different port, or are they using the default Express port 3000?  Does `proxy_pass http://client:3000;` work better?  (`EXPOSE` does almost nothing.)

Comment: Express is running on port 5000. Do I need to expose port 3000 for proxy_pass http://client:3000 or no need?

Comment: Or map it in docker-compose?

Comment: If the server is listening on port 5000, then use that port number everywhere (in `proxy_pass:`, as the second number in `ports:`, in `EXPOSE` if you choose to have that).

Comment: But I read somewhere that we don't need to expose ports when all services lie in the same network, they can communicate without ports? Am I having the wrong idea?

Comment: it was also written than we are using reverse proxy so they'll all run on same port. I think I am confused overall

Comment: Any TCP-based communication always needs a server port number.  `http://name` with no port number is port 80.  If it's not port 80 then it needs to be included in the URL.

Comment: ok I'll try and get back to you

Comment: Thanks, react app is working but giving "GET http://localhost/api 404 (Not Found)" on access to api

Comment: I realized what was wrong, Thanks a lotttt for your help. I was struggling.